# How to retrieve compile command for C/C++ file in a vscode extension

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to build a visual studio code extension for include what you use. In order to properly invoke the tool I must find out which parameters are passed to the compiler. I know I can retrieve this data form the "compile_commands.json" file.

I was wondering if it is possible to retrieve this from the running vscode c/c++ plugin.

Answer (score 1):

vscode c/c++ plugin requires this file itself to provide better IntelliSense, otherwise it uses own tag parser algorithms and knows nothing about compile instructions for particular file.